# Objective C: When to use NSCopying and and to use @property(copy)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management, deep-copy

According to Apple docs:

**NSCopying**
*Copying an object creates a new object with the same class and properties as the original object. You copy an object when you want your own version of the data that the object contains.*
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCopying.html

**@property(copy)** *Use copy to automatically send the newly-assigned object a -copy message (which will create a copy of the passed object and assign that copy to the property instead*.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCopying.html

I know there is already a lot of content individually on these concepts.

But can someone explain the scenarios where:

1. These 2 can be used interchangeably
2. These 2 need to be used together to achieve something.(Because if we create a custom class how will the system directly create a copy if we create object of such a class with @property(copy))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding the `copy` property. It always uses the `NSCopying` behavior. `NSCopying` defines a `copy` method to create a new instance from an existing instance and `copy` property uses this method to save data, instead of retaining the original instance.

To understand the need for `copy` property, first we have to understand the difference between mutable and immutable objects. For example, let's look at `NSMutableArray` and `NSArray`. The first is mutable, the latter immutable. When we pass `NSMutableArray` somewhere and retain it, we want to avoid other classes from changing our internal state, that's why we want to copy the current value of the array instead of saving the original mutable array.

For example:

```
@interface A : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *array1;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *array2;
@end

NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[array addObject:@"a"];
[array addObject:@"b"];
[array addObject:@"c"];

A *a = [[A alloc] init];
a.array1 = array;
a.array2 = array;

// now we have changed the contents of a.array1 but a.array2 stays the same!
[array addObject:@"d"];
```

An interesting point is that immutable objects don't return a new instance from `copy`, they return `self` because if an object is immutable, it does not matter.

Comment: I think so you intended to declare array1 and array2 as mutable arrays, right? Also, during assignment it should be the other way round, array = a.array1, array = a.array2; right?

Comment: @7vikram7 No, I did it as intended. The problem is that you can assign a mutable array to an immutable array and if you then mutate it, you are changing the internal state of `a`. That's the whole point of copy properties.

Answer (score 0):

When you use @property(copy) id xxx; the exact code will be like this:

```
-(id)xxx {   
  return [_xxx copy]; 
}
```

The `NSCopying` is a protocol to indicate a class can be copied. You need to implement your class's copy method to make it work.